# While loop for validation in java

Tags: java

I would like to create a while loop in my "Member" constructor (code to follow - its pretty simple) to ensure that the member id is 10 characters, or the pin number is 4 characters

e.g. While the id/pinNumber id not 10/4 long
stop the constructor being made
print "Please enter a id/pinNumber is 10/4 characters long"

this is my code

```
 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class Member
 */
public Member(String giveName, String giveID, String givePinNumber, int giveMoney)
{
    memberName = giveName;
    id = giveID;
    if(id.length() > 10)
        System.out.println("Please input an id less than 10 characters");

    pinNumber = givePinNumber;
    if(pinNumber.length() > 10)
        System.out.println("Please input a pinNumber less than 10 characters");

    store = null;
    item = null;
    money = giveMoney;
}
```

Comment: it's quite uncommon to do something like this in the constructor but that's your decision. But still, what is your question?

Comment: Cool, now what's your question ?? If you are expecting `sysout` to prompt the user than that is not the case.

Comment: Throw an exception or substring the parameters to desired length

Comment: Keep in mind that arguments can also be `null`, which should be checked before calling `length()` on them.

Comment: I'd suggest to instead throw an exception (IllegalArgument or something like that) in the Constructor if the value does not match the contract. Then loop in the method where the instance is being tried to create. OR provide a Validator where you can check inputs that returns an appropriate result. But looping and doing User-I/O in a constructor ... ouch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question seems to attract very broad/parly wrong answers, i'll try to clarify some things here:

It **is possible** to loop in the constructor to get input from the console, but i would highly suggest not to use that kind of code:

```
Member(String giveName, String giveID, String givePinNumber, int giveMoney) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    id = giveID;
    while (id.length() != 10) {
        System.out.println("Enter id with length of 10: ");
        id = sc.nextLine();
    }

    pinNumber = givePinNumber;
    while (pinNumber.length() != 4) {
        System.out.println("Enter pin-number with length of 4: ");
        pinNumber = sc.nextLine();
    }

    store = null;
    item = null;
    money = giveMoney;

    sc.close();
}
```

---

Usually this would be done from the one who is creating the member object! If the Member Object is created my the main-method you could/would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String id;
    System.out.println("Please enter id: (length must be 10)");
    while ((id = sc.nextLine()).length() != 10)
        System.out.println("Length of id must be 10, try again: ");

    String pin;
    System.out.println("Please enter id: (length must be 10)");
    while ((pin = sc.nextLine()).length() != 4)
        System.out.println("Length of pin must be 4, try again: ");

    sc.close();

    Member foo = new Member("Peter", id, pin, 1000000);
}
```

and your Member-constructor could look like this:

```
Member(String giveName, String giveID, String givePinNumber, int giveMoney) {
    if (giveID.length() != 10)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("ID-length must be 10!");
    if (givePinNumber.length() != 4)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("PIN-length must be 4!");

    id = giveID;
    pinNumber = givePinNumber;
    store = null;
    item = null;
    money = giveMoney;

}
```

This method will make your code clear and readable but much more important: reusable! Consider a java-app where you don't have a console... You wouldn't be able to use your Member class anymore!

Comment: This is great - my lecturer told me to put validations in my constructor and I had no idea on what to do, but this has definitely cleared it up for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this kind of validations are of the view layer:
   * Ask values
   * Make validations
   * Show errors and ask correct values
When you call the constructor, the data passed to it must be ok.

Because of this, you don't need validations in constructor.

In fact, the constructor's objective is to initialice the class' fields.  No validations, nor throw exceptions.